# Running intern-runner with external library relying on window fails. ReferenceError: window is not defined

Tags: javascript, intern

I've been trying to make Intern work at the same time as another library called Pact, for contract testing. My dummy test looks like this:

```
define([
  'intern!object',
  'intern/chai!expect',
  'bower_components/pact-consumer-js-dsl/dist/pact-consumer-js-dsl.js'
], function(registerSuite, expect) {
  registerSuite({
    name: 'Test',

    'login form': function() {
      var _this = this;

      return this.remote
        .get(loginUrl)
        ...
        .end();
    }
  });
});
```

The problem is that if I try to run the test including the Pact library (line 4), Intern shows an error because `window` is not defined.

`Warning: ReferenceError: window is not defined`

If I remove the inclusion of the library, the test runs correctly, opens the browser and it makes everything that it is supposed to do. I am running this already as `functionalSuite` and I am using `intern-runner` instead of client. I tried using Chrome or PhantomJS with no luck.

It is not a problem just with the Pact library, it seems to happen every time that I try to use something else that also uses `window` or `document` (with jQuery for instance, it can't find `document`).

My config for Intern looks like this:

```
define({

  proxyPort: 9999,

  proxyUrl: 'http://localhost:9999/',

  capabilities: {
    'selenium-version': '2.45.0'
  },

  environments: [
    { browserName: 'chrome' }
  ],

  tunnel: 'NullTunnel',

  maxConcurrency: 3,

  functionalSuites: ['test/intern/integration/login'],

  excludeInstrumentation: /^tests|bower_components|node_modules\//

});
```

If somebody knows a solution for this I will be extremely grateful :)

Comment: What are you using the Pact library for exactly?  Functional test suites themselves do not run in a browser context, they run in Node.  The page loaded into each remote environment is what actually loads in a browser context and has access to the DOM.

Comment: That seems to be the problem... The two contexts. We want to use Pact to have a contract between the frontend and the backend, and we wanted to kill two birds with a stone by using Pact in the functional test, as we want a mocked backend for the functional tests, not the real one.

Then we have a different problem, and that is... How can we mock the backend in a functional test with Intern?

Comment: How were you planning to use the Pact library on the backend if it doesn’t support Node.js (= `window is not defined`)?